# What is the indefinite integral of $\int e^{\frac{1}{x^2 - a^2}} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

I am looking for a solution to the following integral and finding it quite hard to find one ($|x| < a$):

$$ \int e^{\frac{1}{x^2 - a^2}} dx $$

I've tried to solve it with several substitutions, such as $u := x^2 - a^2$, but it yielded no other integral that seemed easier to solve. I've also tried to separate the exponent into something like $\frac{A}{x-a} + \frac{B}{x+a}$ and then integrating by parts, but also this approach didn't work out.

The reason for this question is the following: I need to modify this function, such that the integral from $-a$ to $a$ equals 1. That's why I came up with this integral, but if you see a way to find the required modification without having to integrate, that'll be fine as well.
Thanks!

Comment: Can this be one of those functions that you cannot possibly integrate like $\int \frac{1}{e^{x^2}}$ (which is somewhat similar to the error function)

Comment: @StringerBell How did you come up with this? I don't think an antiderivative for the integrand function is an elementary function.

Comment: I don't think this has a primitive that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @GitGud I need to modify this function, such that the Integral from $-a$ to $a$ equals 1, so actually it is not an undefined integral, but I don't think this makes it easier :)

Comment: @StringerBell I suggest you add that to that question, whilst clarifying what you mean with modifying the function.

Comment: @GitGud makes sense - see edits in my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you just want $-a$ to $a$, use change of variable $u=-1/(x^2-a^2
)$ as follows:
$$
\int_{-a}^a \exp\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}\;dx = 2 \int_{0}^a \exp\frac{1}{x^2-a^2}\;dx
= \int_{1/a^2}^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u^{3/2}\sqrt{a^2u-1}}\;du =
\frac{e^{-1/(2a^2)}}{a}\left(K_1\left(\frac{1}{2a^2}\right)-K_0\left(\frac{1}{2a^2}\right)\right)
$$

Comment: What are $K_0$ and $K_1$? Or rather, how are they called?

Comment: Did you subsitute u with $\exp(-1/(x^2 - a^2))$ or only $u = -1/(x^2 - a^2)$? And why the the minus? Shouldn't you then be integrating from $-1/a^2$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Bessel functions ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you. It's never too late to learn...+1.

Comment: The minus is so $u$ is positive when $0<x<a$.

Comment: Could you elaborate the last step? How did you arrive at that answer using bessel functions?@GEdgar

Comment: @Kugelblitz ... Table of integrals?

Comment: Fair enough....